# Arduino yun is not creating it's wifi?

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun

I have installed Arduino software into my PC and copied the bin files into the memory card that has to be fixed into Arduino yun.

After switching on the yun board it is not creating any Arduino yun wifi connection.

Can you help me to overcome this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no code that enables the WiFi, it won't be enabled.

Here's the link:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc14

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to reset wiffi. Press for 3 seconds. After this you must await for a while. Some leds will open and close. This process takes about 2 or 3 minutes. After this. Your white led will be flashing. That is all.
Have in mind some points:
First time you have to connect your yun by usb. Then you have to openIDE and choose IP PORT which will be showed(192.168....). Then go to your browser and type Ip and configurate your yun for wifi.